# Turn searches into tag searches if the search term is a synonym of a top 40 tag

Tags: feature-request, search

We already have the feature that if a tag is in the top 40 (I think), searches for the contents of the tag search for the tag instead. For example, searching for "java" returns results with posts tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java). This is good, but on [gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) (I don't know about other sites), some of our top tags have synonyms that people are more likely to search for. If people want to know about Star Wars: The Old Republic, they might search "the old republic", but they won't find it because the tag is [swtor](/questions/tagged/swtor).

So, I propose that if a tag is a synonym of a top 40 tag, it is also a candidate for searches turning into tag searches. So in the case I just described, searches for "the old republic" would redirect to a tag search for [swtor](/questions/tagged/swtor).

Comment: Oh, I agree, but it can't hurt to make incremental improvements in the mean time

Answer (score 4):

No! Please don't do this. If I want to search for questions tagged `foo`, I will search for `[foo]`. I often don't want to limit my search to only those posts that are tagged with my search string. What if the post is incorrectly tagged? What if the tag is a relatively common word and I want to search for that?

We already have a way of searching for tags, I see no reason to force every search to be a tag search just because the search string happens to also be a tag. Unfortunately, this is already being done so, at the very least, let's not extend it to all tags!